# CSS @keyframe Animation Removing whole button instead of just border

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, keyframe

I have a CSS keyframe animation that outlines the border of the button. However, when I try to reverse the animation on mouse off, it removes the inset box shadow instead of the gradient border.

As you can see below, I've tried to set the border and background again in `mouseLeaveAnimationClass`. That does not solve the problem either. Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.get-started');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  els[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
    e.target.classList.add('mouseleaveAnimationClass');
  });
  els[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove('mouseleaveAnimationClass');
  });
}
```

```css
 body {

   background-color: black;

 }

#button {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 75px;
  position: relative;
  top: -30%;
  left: calc(50% - 125px);
}

.get-started {
  --borderWidth: 5px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: var(--borderWidth);
  background-color: #8551FF;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.get-started:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

.get-started:hover:after {
  background: linear-gradient(60deg, #f79533, #f37055, #ef4e7b, #a166ab, #5073b8, #1098ad, #07b39b, #6fba82);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-size: 300% 300%;
  animation: frame-enter 1s forwards ease-in-out reverse, gradient-animation 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.get-started.mouseleaveAnimationClass {
  background: linear-gradient(60deg, #f79533, #f37055, #ef4e7b, #a166ab, #5073b8, #1098ad, #07b39b, #6fba82);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-size: 300% 300%;
  animation: frame-enter 1s forwards ease-in-out;
}


/* motion */

@keyframes gradient-animation {
  0% {
    background-position: 15% 0%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 85% 100%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 15% 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes frame-enter {
  0% {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 5px), 5px calc(100% - 5px), 5px 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
  }
  25% {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 5px), calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 5px), calc(100% - 5px) 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
  }
  50% {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 0%, 0% 0%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="get-started" id="button">Get Started</div>
```

[Runnable Example](https://codepen.io/dish_uwu/pen/eYYBeoz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original problem, the `.get-started.mouseleaveAnimationClass {` rule is applied to the element itself, and not to the `::after` pseudo-element, and that's why the element is clipped. However, this won't solve your main problem - the reverse animation.

I've updated your code with a solution that is not super DRY, and you can probably improve it.

On the 1st hover only, the `.ready` class is added to the button. This enables the `frame-leave` animation, without running it. Whenever you `:hover` the element the `frame-enter` animation is applied, and as soon as you leave the element, the `frame-leave` is called again.

**Notes:**

1. `frame-enter` and `frame-leave` are the same animation. Using a different name allows us to replace them.
2. When you enter and then leave in the middle of the animation it will jump from the enter to the leave animation.

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.get-started');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  els[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
    e.target.classList.add('ready');
  }, { once: true });
}
```

```css
#button {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 75px;
  position: relative;
  top: -30%;
  left: calc(50% - 125px);
}

.get-started {
  --borderWidth: 5px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: var(--borderWidth);
  background-color: #8551FF;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.get-started::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(60deg, #f79533, #f37055, #ef4e7b, #a166ab, #5073b8, #1098ad, #07b39b, #6fba82);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-size: 300% 300%;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.get-started.ready::after {
  animation: frame-leave 1s forwards ease-in-out, gradient-animation 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.get-started.ready:hover::after {
  animation: frame-enter 1s forwards ease-in-out reverse, gradient-animation 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}


/* motion */

@keyframes gradient-animation {
  0% {
    background-position: 15% 0%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 85% 100%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 15% 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes frame-enter {
  0% {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 5px), 5px calc(100% - 5px), 5px 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
  }
  25% {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 5px), calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 5px), calc(100% - 5px) 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
  }
  50% {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
  }
  75% {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 0%, 0% 0%);
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
}

@keyframes frame-leave {
  0% {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 5px), 5px calc(100% - 5px), 5px 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
  }
  25% {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 5px), calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 5px), calc(100% - 5px) 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
  }
  50% {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, calc(100% - 5px) 5px, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
  }
  75% {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 5px 0%, 0% 0%);
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="get-started" id="button">Get Started</div>
```